# CakePHP tmp folder access for mod_php and mod_fcgid

Tags: apache, cakephp, chown, mod-fcgid

CakePHP needs to change owner of temp folders like this:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#tmp-directory-permissions

```
# chown -R username app/tmp
```

When I use Apache with `mod_php`, username must be `apache`.
When I use Apache with `mod_fcgid`, username must be `myswebsiteuser`.

I need to make some tryouts to check the performance of the `fcgid` vs. `mod_php`. So When I switch the php type, I get tons of errors in minutes. I run script that changes owner of the folder from apache to mywebsiteuser, remove old temporary files and wait cakephp to create new ones with new user. I need to combine old and new log files also.

It seems like [chown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) permits to set user groups. Is there a way to set "tmp" folders so they can be used in mod_php and mod_fcgid, without switching owners ?

(I own the server, it has CentOS and it has only one website. Also Plesk 11.5)

Similar: [What are the right ownership & permissions to the CakePHP app/tmp folder for production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899012/what-are-the-right-ownership-permissions-to-the-cakephp-app-tmp-folder-for-pro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a group:

```
# groupadd mygroup
```

Open the groups file:

```
# vi /etc/group
```

In the last line there exists a line like this:

```
mygroup:x:510:
```

Look for the username of the mod_fcgid, if you website is mywebsite.com, then possibly it is "mywebsite".

You need to add 2 users to your new group "apache" and "mywebsite".

```
mygroup:x:510:apache,mywebsite
```

Now change owner and mod of the folders like this:

```
# chown -R mywebsite:mygrup /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/tmp/
# chmod -R 664 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/app/tmp/
```

Now temp folder is both writeable by mod_php (apache) mod_fcgid (mywebsite).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a cakephp issue, neither apache. You just need a basic linux file/folder permissions understanding.

Quick and dirty solution: Set `tmp` to 777 (`chmod 777 <path>/tmp`) it will solve your problem for your tests.

Then do some reading on the above subject and reset permissions/ownership accordingly.